# What does Node<E> represent in this Linked List Java sample code?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes

I'm studying **Linked Lists** and I don't understand this example from my textbook. I understand the concept of generics (although perhaps not very well at this point) and implemented several generic classes in my own code and I've read and watched a lot of tutorials, but I still can't wrap my head around what **Node< E >** actually does (and actually what actually *is*, is it a type?), so I cannot really test this code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {

    private class Node<E> {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
            element = e;
            next = n;
        }

        public E getElement() { 
            return element; 
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() { 
            return next; 
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> n) { 
            next = n; 
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried for example to create both a Node object or a SinglyLinkedList object like this:

```
SinglyLinkedList<E> NodeEl = new SinglyLinkedList<E>();
Node <E> node = new Node<E>();
```

and passing all kinds of objects to them to no avail. I'm obviously missing something but I can't understand what.

Comment: Paste your import statements too. Because There are multiple classes with name Node with different namespaces.

Comment: @Shriram Done. The only import I used is java.utils.*, however the book doesn't actually mention any, it was my decision to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class SinglyLinkedList<E>` represents a linked list of elements of a generic type.

You can, for example, create a linked list of `String`s with:

```
SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>();
```

`class Node<E>` is an inner class of the `SinglyLinkedList` class. It represents an single link in the linked list, which contains a single element (of a generic type) and a reference to the next link.

Since `Node` is an inner class of `SinglyLinkedList`, you cannot create an instance of it without supplying an instance of the enclosing instance (i.e. an instance of the `SinglyLinkedList` class).

Therefore you can only write

```
Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
```

inside instance (i.e. non-static) methods of the `SinglyLinkedList` class, where an enclosing instance (of the `SinglyLinkedList` class) is available.

That said, if `Node` should hold an element of the same type as the element type of `SinglyLinkedList`, it shouldn't be generic. It can simply use the generic type parameter of the enclosing class (`SinglyLinkedList`):

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {

    private class Node {
        private E element;
        private Node next;

        public Node(E e, Node n) {
            element = e;
            next = n;
        }

        public E getElement() { 
            return element; 
        }

        public Node getNext() { 
            return next; 
        }

        public void setNext(Node n) { 
            next = n; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it's a bit clearer now, but I'm still quite fuzzy on the implementation. The compiler accepts `SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>();` but I still don't understand what I'm supposed to do with this object. Also I cannot seem to be able to instantiate a Node, both `Node node = new Node();` and `Node<E> node = new Node<E>();` don't work.

Comment: @Sheenan I assumed you posted an incomplete `SinglyLinkedList` class. I expect the full class to contain methods such as `add` and `remove`. You can't create an instance of `Node` from outside the `SinglyLinkedList` class as long as `Node` remains a private class.